# Запрос к MySQL проходит через sqlyog, но не проходит на сервере

Tags: php, sql, mysql

```
$res = mysql_query(" SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM EVENTS WHERE `action` = `2010-01-25`  ");
```

Если делаю запрос через sqlyog, то все ок, а на сервере - нет, пишется, что ошибка в том, что дата, как я понял, не строковая, как это победить?

Запрос, который прошел в sqlyog:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM EVENTS WHERE `action` = "2010-01-25";
```

Comment: ну кавычки же не те в php у вас для даты... внимательнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query(" SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM EVENTS WHERE `action` = '2010-01-25'  ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y');
        -> '2013-05-01'
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('May 1, 2013','%M %d,%Y');
        -> '2013-05-01'
```

[Из строки в дату](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: Интересно почему мой ответ заминусовали)))

Comment: потому что это не решение

Comment: Нда в одном случае у вас работает, в другом не работает. Даты должны сравниваться с датами, строки со строками. Переведите вашу строку в дату, а потом используйте в своем решении. Неявное приведение зло, в вашем случае это видно. Если у вас дата хранится как строка в таблице, то это еще хуже)

Comment: Я исхожу из той задачи, которую надо решить, идеальное решение, "как должно быть" я понимаю.

Comment: Идеально решение это сравнивать даты с датами, и не думать о том, пройдет ли запрос в это вашем sqlyog или в коде приложения, или в из консоли MySQL.

Comment: Значит делаем вывод: идеальное решение - не решение ^_^

Comment: Нет не так, у меня был вопрос как решить эту задачу, я понимаю что можно сделать глобально переделать бд и переделать в дампе за 3 года формат данных, но исходил из решения - обойтись малой кровью и решить задачу.